# Multiple ways of authentication with spring oauth2 and keycloak

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I have a Spring boot project which runs authentication with spring oauth2 token provider.
Now there is a idea to support a autentication with Keycloak, so that username and password will be stored in Keycloak and it will provide the access token.
Idea is to keep the oauth token store and provider, and as well to have a keycloak one, but to keep the roles and acces right part in spring. Keycloak will only be used for some users as a token provider instead of Spring one and to have a refresh token. So all the user data and access rights and roles are still be done by spring, from database, only the part where it authenticates username and password will be in Keycloak which provides a token.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    private AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager)
                .antMatchers("/service/*").fullyAuthenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean(name = "authenticationManagerBean")
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }

    @Bean
    public AffirmativeBased accessDecisionManager() {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<?>> accessDecisionVoters = new ArrayList<>();
        accessDecisionVoters.add(new ScopeVoter());
        accessDecisionVoters.add(new RoleVoter());
        accessDecisionVoters.add(new AuthenticatedVoter());

        AffirmativeBased accessDecisionManager = new AffirmativeBased(accessDecisionVoters);
        return accessDecisionManager;
    }
```

And there is a Custom client service which grants access rights:

```
@Component
public class CustomClientService implements ClientDetailsService {

    private static Map<String, BaseClientDetails> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    AccessRightsService accessRightsService;
    
    
    @Override
    public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String paramString) throws ClientRegistrationException {
        ...
```

Also there is a custom TokenStore class:

```
public class MyTokenServices extends DefaultTokenServices {
    
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyTokenServices.class);
    
    public UserService userService;
    
    public AccessRightsService accessRightService;

    private TokenStore my_tokenStore;
    
    @Override
    public void setTokenStore(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        my_tokenStore = tokenStore;
    }
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public OAuth2AccessToken createAccessToken(OAuth2Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        OAuth2AccessToken retVal= super.createAccessToken(authentication);
        if(retVal instanceof DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) {
            DefaultOAuth2AccessToken defRetVal =  (DefaultOAuth2AccessToken)retVal;
            log.info("New loging request"+ defRetVal.toString());
//          defRetVal.setExpiration( Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().plus(8,ChronoUnit.HOURS).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
            my_tokenStore.storeAccessToken(defRetVal, authentication);
        }
        return retVal;
         
    }
    
    @Override
    public OAuth2Authentication loadAuthentication(String accessTokenValue)
            throws AuthenticationException, InvalidTokenException {
        OAuth2Authentication retVal = super.loadAuthentication(accessTokenValue);
        OAuth2Request oldRequest = retVal.getOAuth2Request();
        
        User user = userService.getUserByUsername(oldRequest.getClientId());
        if(changeAutheticator(retVal, user)) {
            HashSet<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
            user.getRoles().forEach(a->authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(a.getRoleName())));
            
            Set<String> accessRights = accessRightService.getUserAccessRights(user);
            if(accessRights != null) {
                accessRights.forEach(rihgt->{
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(rihgt));
                });
            }
            OAuth2Request newRequest  = new OAuth2Request(retVal.getOAuth2Request().getRequestParameters(),
                oldRequest.getClientId(), authorities, oldRequest.isApproved(), oldRequest.getScope(), 
                oldRequest.getResourceIds(), oldRequest.getRedirectUri(), oldRequest.getResponseTypes(), oldRequest.getExtensions());
        
            retVal = new OAuth2Authentication(newRequest, retVal.getUserAuthentication());
        }
        return retVal;
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Method that check do we need to change authenticator
     * @param retVal
     * @param user
     * @return
     */
    private boolean changeAutheticator(OAuth2Authentication auth, User user) {
        if(user == null) return false;
        if(user != null ) {
            if(user.getRoles() != null) {
                if(auth.getOAuth2Request()!=null && auth.getOAuth2Request().getAuthorities() != null){
                    for(Role role:user.getRoles()){
                        if(!auth.getOAuth2Request().getAuthorities().stream().anyMatch(a->a.getAuthority().equals(role.getRoleName()))){
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    for(GrantedAuthority ga : auth.getOAuth2Request().getAuthorities()) {
                        if(!user.getRoles().stream().anyMatch(a->a.getRoleName().equals(ga.getAuthority()))){
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I was trying to implement a multiple authentiaction like the one from other stackoverflow but that was not a solution. Thinking that I should provide a custom authentication provider with Keycloak or still like not having a solution in head.

Answer (score 0):

I use Keycloak to federate other identities: the only issuers that clients and resource-servers trust are Keycloak instances or realms. Other identity sources are hidden behind it.

With that config, roles are put into tokens by Keycloak, just as any other claims (for the last project I worked on, roles referential is LDAP but it could be a custom database table or Keycloak default one).

It's pretty easy to connect Keycloak to your user database and it comes with many features that I don't want to code and maintain (multi-factor authentication, social login, users, clients and resource-servers management screens,...)